# Portrait Video Camera Tracking shift

Tags: tracking

is it possible to track the vertical (portrait) video ?
(I tried every step I did to Normal Landscape Video format)

The solve error is 0.2 (looks good) , but after creating the scene , all track points are shifting..Floating.

I tried manually trackers and Auto Feature Trackers

---

I tried several video ratio with the same clip (smooth handhold shot), get the result below.

**Situation_01:**
Portrait video ratio, result shifting.

[image]

**Situation_02:**
Rotated 90 degree as landscape ratio, rock solid tracking result.

[image]

**Situation_03:**
Keep 16:9 ratio but with Black Matte, solid camera resolved.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Technically there is no difference between landscape and portrait. Can you please elaborate on "shifting" and add more detail to your question?

Comment: please add a link to the video. There is no need to rotate, or add pillars around the video. Also please add an image that shows the settings for the camera (lens and sensor size) in the video clip editor.

Comment: No link to the video?

Comment: @susu How can I upload a video?

Comment: Find a site where you can upload the file and add the link as part of your question. Google drive or dropbox or any other service would work.

Comment: @susu Thank you . Here is the Link included jpg sequence:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P0M2MpvNtfgcsun1NQzNTj-4HnX7T4wn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: There is hardly any motion in the video. To determine 3d information you need parallax(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax)

Comment: Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking

Comment: @susu But why I can get rock solid tracking result after turned it to Landscape video ratio, and it will be shifting when stay portrait ratio

Answer (score 2):

**Answer**

Yes it is possible to track vertical video, so that is not the issue at all.

**Not an answer**, but getting to the core of the issue.

The most common problem with tracking is using the wrong model for solving. If the camera is stationary or just rotating (paning and tilting) then you need to solve as "tripod".

Read:

[How can I get better results when doing camera motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking).

To help you further you would need to edit your original post and show a link to the video, and share some images of the interface showing what you have so far.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the camera lens angle and the background video of the camera offset on x or y axis to match your trackers  and you will be fine for like a 15 sec clip then it starts drifting. Better we shoot in landscape mode form now on!